# When Flashing New ROM onto Device, Can the Original Still Be Used?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, rom, operating-system

I've recently rooted my phone and I was thinking about adding a custom recovery and ROM. However, my original OS still must be accessed. Is this possible?

Comment: MultiROM should be what you're looking for... but that is only limited to a few phones that support it / has it ported over.

Comment: OK. Submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MultiROM](https://github.com/Tasssadar/multirom) should be what you're looking for, though it's only limited to a few of popular devices that support it / has it ported over, e.g. Nexus series, Redmi, etc. Look up in XDA-Developers if your device has a port.